# How can I know data changes for elasticsearch indexing?

Tags: database, indexing, elasticsearch, relational-database, elasticsearch-plugin

I want to ask, not to technical, but more about concept. If I want to implement elasticsearch to indexing the data on my database. So, the user can search the data from elasticsearch. The condition is I use SQL Server database and elasticsearch.

So, how can I know if the data changes and I need to indexing the changes into elasticsearch, so that user can receive the newest information from elasticsearch.

I need your suggest all, Thanks

Comment: Here is a short answer that should get you started: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31995648/logstash-jdbc-connector-time-based-data/32001923#32001923

Comment: If you're using an ORM, you can reindex Elasticsearch documents whenever your models are changing. You can also trigger a chain reindex if the data stored in a table is replicated in multiple ES indexes.