# The sync principle of logstash-input-jdbc?

Tags: mysql, elasticsearch, synchronization

I want to know the sync principle of logstash-input-jdbc?
I know it is based on the time compare method like :

```
select
   *
   from
   cc
  where cc.modified_at > :sql_last_value,
```

Does it also based on database trigger methon.
When I grep the logstash-input-jdbc source, I find there is no any trigger information.

If you know, please help me.
Any help would be sincerely appreciate.

Comment: You need to configure the `schedule` parameter, which will act as the trigger. Everytime the schedule expression is triggered, a new query will be made in your DB.

Comment: oh, I get it. Can you explain the method deeply. The deeper the better.

Comment: This answer should help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31995648/logstash-jdbc-connector-time-based-data/32001923#32001923

Comment: thk, Do you know the  default schedule => "* * * * *"  exact meaning? I know the seq is: min, hour day, month, year. If all set *, the meaning I test is 1 min update once. I want to know the exact meaning? please help me.

Comment: This is all nicely explained in the [official documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-jdbc.html#_scheduling) ;-)

Comment: Tks, I got result: execute this input statement on the minute, every minute.

Comment: Glad you figured it out.